# Update ionic/angular from 5.0.0 to 5.7.0 Potassium

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

Currently my Ionic is running on `"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0"`. `ionic -v` is `6.17.1`. I can't find a way in the documents to update my ionic to `5.7.0 Potassium`.

The following did not work:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```

Comment: try `npm update` in your project root. this will update all dependencies. if you just want to update ionic/angular. try: `npm i @ionic/angular@latest`

Comment: I did update individually with npm i @ionic/*@latest. Please post it as an answer so that I can make it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `npm update` in your project root to update all dependencies.

if you just want to update `ionic/angular` or just a single module.

try: `npm i @ionic/angular@latest`